# EV3 Brick: Powers on then off and won't stay powered on

Tags: ev3

I have an EV3 brick that when I press the power button the red lights all come on - the display shows starting up but after 3 seconds it powers off. The same happens when I press the power and right keys to update.

Any suggestions on how to get the unit to power on properly or is this not a software issue?

Comment: Did you try new batteries?

Comment: I did try with new batteries.

Answer (score 2):

If the batteries are new and not even the update mode stays on, then something is wrong with the hardware. You should reach out to LEGO customer support to see if they can help.